# Missing actual argument when calling a subroutine with optional arguments

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

My IDE is Visual Studio 2010 with integrated Intel Fortran compiler. The version of compiler is: Intel Parallel Studio XE 2011.

I am not experienced programer in Fortran so I need a little help about using optional argument in public procedure from derived type. This is my example code:

```
MODULE DERIVED_TYPE

 TYPE , PUBLIC :: SOME_TYPE

  INTEGER , PRIVATE :: V_INT

   CONTAINS

      PROCEDURE , PUBLIC :: CALL_V_INT => CALL_DATA_V_INT
      PROCEDURE , PUBLIC :: TAKE_V_INT => TAKE_DATA_V_INT

 END TYPE SOME_TYPE

 PRIVATE :: CALL_DATA_V_INT
 PRIVATE :: TAKE_DATA_V_INT

CONTAINS

! PUBLIC PROCEDURES

  SUBROUTINE CALL_DATA_V_INT( THIS , IA , IB , IC )

    CLASS( SOME_TYPE ) :: THIS
    INTEGER , INTENT( IN ) :: IA , IC
    INTEGER , INTENT( IN ) , OPTIONAL :: IB

    IF( .NOT. PRESENT( IB ) ) THEN

        THIS%V_INT = IA + IC

    ELSE

        THIS%V_INT = IA + IB + IC

    END IF

  END SUBROUTINE CALL_DATA_V_INT

  FUNCTION TAKE_DATA_V_INT ( THIS ) RESULT( RES )

    CLASS( SOME_TYPE ) :: THIS
    INTEGER :: RES

    RES = THIS%V_INT

  END FUNCTION TAKE_DATA_V_INT

END MODULE DERIVED_TYPE

PROGRAM OPTIONAL_ARG

USE , NON_INTRINSIC :: DERIVED_TYPE

IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER :: I
INTEGER , PARAMETER :: N = 3

CLASS( SOME_TYPE ) , POINTER :: P_SOME_TYPE

TYPE( SOME_TYPE ) , DIMENSION( N ) , TARGET :: ARR_V_INT

DO I = 1 , N

   P_SOME_TYPE => ARR_V_INT( I )

   CALL P_SOME_TYPE%CALL_V_INT( I , 5 )

   WRITE( * , * ) P_SOME_TYPE%TAKE_V_INT()

END DO

END PROGRAM OPTIONAL_ARG
```

At the end of compiling proces i got this kind of message in build window:
`Missing actual argument for argument 'ic'`

What is wrong with this example?

I also try to move optional argument to latest position in argument list and in that case there is no error message.

Can I get detail explanation for optional argument position in argument list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should normally try to put optional arguments at the end of the argument list. What happens when you do call such as

```
  subroutine sub (a, b, c)
    real :: a, c
    real, optional :: b

  ...

  call sub(1.,2.)
```

is that the compiler must assume that the `1.` is for `a` and the `2.` is for `b`. Then the argument for `c` is missing.

Instead one can use named arguments after the missing optional one

```
  call sub(1, c=2.)
```

So in your case you could do

```
CALL P_SOME_TYPE%CALL_V_INT( I , IC = 5 )
```

if you don't want to have the optional `IB` at the end of the argument list.

Comment: Is there need for using explicit interface for public procedure `CALL_V_INT ` ?

Comment: Yes, but the explicit interface is provided by the module. https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/01/05/doctor-fortran-gets-explicit-again Do not confuse explicit interface and interface blocks.